# Как быстро найти хотя бы одно решение сравнения x^p0 = 1 (mod p)?

Tags: сравнение, простые-числа, модули

Есть сравнение `a^p0 = 1 (mod p)`, где известны `p0` и `p` - большие простые числа.

Нужно программно найти любое `a > 1`.

Простой перебор `a` выполняется очень долго. Есть более быстрый вариант найти хотя бы одно решение?

Comment: Есть алгоритмы вычисления радикалов в конечном поле. Это решается прежде всего математически.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ.

Нужно выбрать случайное h из (1; p - 1).

Тогда с достаточно большой вероятностью x = h^[(p-1)/p0] mod p будет подходить под условие x^p0 = 1 (mod p).